# sequence of positive, measurable functions converging pointwise to positive measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $(g_j)_j \in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of positive, measurable functions, with $g_j \le g$ for every $n$, $g$ being the pointwise limit of $g_j$ as $j \rightarrow \infty$. Assume $g$ is positive, measurable, and $\int gd\mu = \infty$. Show $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \int g_j d \mu = \infty$

I am assuming one needs to utilize Fatou's Lemma? I get $$\infty = \int \lim g_j \le \liminf \int g_j \le \lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}\int g_j $$ since $\lim g_j = \liminf g_j$. Is this correct?

Comment: Or $\infty \le \liminf \int g_j \le \limsup \int g_j \le sup \int g_j \le \infty $ so $\limsup$ and $\lim inf$ coincide, so the limit does exist and equals $\infty$?

Comment: No, your argument seems to assume $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty} \int g_j d \mu = \infty$, which is what you want to prove.  But "Fatou's Lemma" is a good hint.

Comment: I'm not very comfortable with $\liminf$, $\limsup$ and so on. Could you explain where exactly I assume $\lim \int g_j = \infty$? As far as I can follow my own proof (the one in the comments), I show that the $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ are both greater than infinity. Thus they must be equal to infinity. Thus they must be equal. Since they are equal, the limit exists. And is equal to $\liminf$and $\limsup$. Which is $\infty$. What is the flaw in this argument?